# Mysql AES_DECRYPT() and Replace function Together?

Tags: mysql

i am trying to replace the message and also decryption of message,
i tried the query:

```
select 
   aes_decrypt(message,'Password')as message,
   replace(message,'#TD1#','\n\n') as message   
from 
  daily 
limit 1;
```

but it is returning 2 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 columns in the select, both of them named message also. Try it like this

```
 SELECT REPLACE(AES_DECRYPT(message,'Password'), '#TD1#','\n\n' ) Message
 FROM daily 
 LIMIT 1;
```

or

```
 SELECT AES_DECRYPT(REPLACE(message, '#TD1#','\n\n' ),'Password') Message
 FROM daily 
 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT REPLACE(AES_DECRYPT(message, 'Password'), '#TD1#', '\n\n') AS message 
FROM   daily 
LIMIT  1;
```